# making mysql 5.7 behave like 5.1

Tags: mysql, database

I have migrated from a server running MySQL version `5.1.73 - Source Distribution` to a server running `5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 - (Ubuntu)`.  Both servers are still up and running.

However, I'm encountering multiple (maddening) errors on queries that used to work, for example:

```
 (Error #1364) Field 'Settings' doesn't have a default value
```

What is a fancy way of saying I didn't write the query on insert to include `Settings` because it didn't need a value yet.

So, I figure I'll go in and `ALTER` that field and give it a default value.  MySQL lovingly tells me

```
#1101 - BLOB, TEXT, .. column 'Settings' can't have a default value
```

Thank you, MySQL..

So it looks like I'm going to have to refactor code, but this could take some time.  **What is the easiest way to make MySQL on the new server emulate 5.1.73?**

UPDATE: It appears that one can make a LONGTEXT field be NULL (vs. NOT NULL), and then the default will in effect be null.  But one cannot have a default that is "empty" or "blank" on a LONGTEXT or similar field.  Lesson I'm learning here, be careful about making a skeleton/bare record entry into the db without referencing certain fields like this explicitly; any non-referenced LONGTEXT field will need to be null - which by the way is a reasonable and logical value vs. blank.

Comment: Those fields **CAN** be nullable. You never specified **what** you tried to set default value as. You see, when you rant about something, at least be sure that you're not the one who is wrong. I didn't downvote you, but for some reason I decided to write a comment that might help you. It's not software's fault, it's **your** fault. It's always your fault, and if you're a programmer or trying to be one - that should be your mantra. Samurais thought about death and tried to embrace it, you should embrace that you are wrong almost always. Don't blame the software you're using.

Comment: You are right, the field I mentioned can be set as null, and it does work.  But if I wanted to avoid NULL values for speed, I can't do that.  For your information, I am creating a service ticket on this project so that I can change all these items, however it's nice to be able to know how to revert a behavior and then make the modifications whilst usage continues.

Comment: I also updated the post to clarify this..

Comment: Wait, what, avoid null values for speed? I'm sorry but you can't justify your decision and throwing performance reasons in. It's also completely false. If you're willing to go as far as to hinder yourself for notion of some imaginary performance, you're doing something very, very, very wrong. Fix your data model **first**. *If* you have performance problems, focus on them when you start feeling it. If we're talking inserts, there's a method that uses transactions to make inserts faster. No amount of silly fiddling with default values will attribute to a millisecond of performance.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the change they made in 5.7 to enforce strict SQL mode by default. The default SQL mode in MySQL 5.7 is: `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-changes for more information.

You might ask, "why don't they make strict mode optional, but leave it off by default?" The answer is, they did—for about 10 years! It was time to make the next step and enforce strict mode by default. It helps bring MySQL into better SQL compliance and compatibility with other standard RDBMS products.

So how can you turn off strict mode to make it act like the previous, more lax SQL mode? It's easy, put this in your /etc/my.cnf:

```
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

You can also enable that change without restarting mysqld:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL sql_mode='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

You probably want to keep NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION on. Engine substitution means for example if you declare a table with ENGINE=InnoDB but the InnoDB storage engine is not enabled for some reason, MySQL will create the table but make it MyISAM silently. This is a bad thing to let happen if you intended it to be InnoDB.

Comment: Hey Bill, thanks for the input.  However, adding `sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` in my.cnf results in a failure to restart mysql.  Remove the line and it the restarts; recommended `journalctl -xe` shows no information about reason.  Similarly, calling `SET GLOBAL sql_mode='NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'` has no effect on the behavior.  I'll keep looking.

Comment: Whenever MySQL fails to start, check its error log for lines that say ERROR.